# JavaScript or AngularJS: Find two objects with matching properties values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am sure this question will have be asked before but for some reason i can't find the right way to find the answer I'm after.

I have two lists of objects. The objects are slightly different but both have a 'ref' property that i can compare them with. I basically want a new list of objects that contains only the objects that are in list1 with a ref value that does not equal any of the ref values for objects in list2.

Currently this is the method I use. **This does work**. However I know that this is probably very inefficient since I am using two loops and looping through the second one countless times. So I'm wondering what the 'proper' method of doing this would be.

```
var add;
for (var x = 0; x < availableQuestions.length; x++) {
    add = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < currentQuestions.length; j++) {
        if (availableQuestions[x].Ref == currentQuestions[j].Ref) {
            add = false;
        }
    }
    if (add) {
        $scope.Questions.push(availableQuestions[x])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create array of `ref` in current questions which would only require iterating that array once.

Then filter the other array comparing to the array of Ref

```
var currentRef = currentQuestions.map(function(item){
     return item.Ref;
});

$scope.Questions = availableQuestions.filter(function(item){
     return currentRef.indexOf(item.Ref) === -1;
});
```

Or even faster would be a hashmap object where `item.Ref` are the property names

```
var currentRef = currentQuestions.reduce(function(obj,item){
         obj[item.Ref] = true;
         return obj;
},{});

$scope.Questions = availableQuestions.filter(function(item){
         return !currentRef[item.Ref];
});
```

Note: all of these methods return new arrays and therefore are not destructive to original arrays

Comment: Very nice, I delete my answer :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for (var x = 0; x < availableQuestions.length; x++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < currentQuestions.length; j++) {
        if (availableQuestions[x].Ref == currentQuestions[j].Ref) {
            $scope.Questions.push(availableQuestions[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add a `break` after you `.push` so it stops looping through currentQuestions and moves to the next availableQuestions.  This will improve the performance. However it looks like you are doing the opposite of what he wants. It looks like he wants to look through all of the currentQuestions and only if it doesn't exist add it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `Set`, you could do something like:

```
var s = new Set(currentQuestions.map(function(q) { return q.Ref }));
availableQuestions.forEach(function(q){
   if(!s.has(q.Ref)){
      $scope.Questions.push(q);
   }
});
```

This assuming that `aq.Ref === cq.Ref`

Answer (score 0):

Convert both of your arrays to associative arrays and then you can do one pass to get the unmatched:

```
var avail = new Array();
var curr = new Array();
angular.forEach(availableQuestions, function(q){
    avail[q.Ref] = q;
});
angular.forEach(currentQuestions, function(q){
    curr[q.Ref] = q;
});
angular.forEach(avail, function(a){
    var q = curr[a.Ref];
    if (q !== null) {
        $scope.Questions.push(a);
    }
});
```